# In C#, how can I create a reusable method where I need to access multiple list types?

Tags: c#, list, interface, refactoring, reusability

I have the following two methods:

```
private void AddHeaderAttachment(AAttachment attachment) {
    string parentId = attachment.ParentId;
    if (this.collectionByIds.TryGetValue(attachment.Id, out MyCollection collection)) {
        if (!collection.AAttachmentByParentIds.TryGetValue(parentId, out List<AAttachment> attachmentList)) {
            attachmentList = new List<AAttachment>();
            collection.AAttachmentByParentIds.Add(parentId, attachmentList);
        }
        attachmentList.Add(attachment);
    }
}

private void AddLineAttachment(BAttachment attachment) {
    string parentId = attachment.ParentId;
    if (this.collectionByIds.TryGetValue(attachment.Id, out MyCollection collection)) {
        if (!collection.BAttachmentByParentIds.TryGetValue(parentId, out List<BAttachment> attachmentList)) {
            attachmentList = new List<BAttachment>();
            collection.BAttachmentByParentIds.Add(parentId, attachmentList);
        }
        attachmentList.Add(attachment);
    }
}
```

The class `MyCollection` looks like this:

```
 public class MyCollection {
        public Dictionary<string, List<AAttachment>> AAttachmentByParentIds = new Dictionary<string, List<AAttachment>>();
        public Dictionary<string, List<BAttachment>> BAttachmentByParentIds = new Dictionary<string, List<BAttachment>>();
}
```

As you can see, the only differences between these two methods above are:

1. The type being provided
2. The property of `MyCollection` which the
   attachment will be added to.

However, both `AAttachment` and `BAttachment` implement:

```
 interface Attachable {
    string ParentId { get; }
 }
```

I would like to create one reusable method.

But I have two obvious problems:

1. If I change the inner `if` to:

```
                if (!collection.AAttachmentByParentIds.TryGetValue(parentId, out List<Attachable> attachmentList)) {
                    attachmentList = new List<Attachable>();
                    collection.lineAttachmentByParentIds.Add(parentId, attachmentList);
                }
```

Visual Studio informs me "Argument 2: cannot convert `out List<Attachable>` to `out List<AttachmentA>`

and

2. How can I alter whether I am referencing `AAttachmentByParentIds` or `BAttachmentByParentIds` on the instance of MyCollection?

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant, have you considered to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I'm rather new with C# and therefore its types, so no, I had not considered this.  Would it be enough to just change the instances of List<> to IEnumerable<>?  Would I need to change them everywhere?  Could making this change have unexected side effects (for example, not being able to use the IEnumerable in some way I am using Lists?)

Comment: You can make your method generic, then have a look at [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) article

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, assuming I made the method more generic using IEnumerable<T> and this doesn't have undesirable side-effects elsewhere, how would I handle that the attachment needs to go into a different Dictionary property on the instance of MyCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be using generics:

```
private void AddHeaderAttachment<TAttachment>(
    Func<MyCollection, Dictionary<string, List<TAttachment>>> attachmentByParentIdsSelector,
    TAttachment attachment) where TAttachment : Attachable
{
    string parentId = attachment.ParentId;
    if (this.collectionByIds.TryGetValue(attachment.Id, out MyCollection collection))
    {
        var attachmentByParentIds = attachmentByParentIdsSelector(collection);
        if (!attachmentByParentIds.TryGetValue(parentId, out List<TAttachment> attachmentList))
        {
            attachmentList = new List<TAttachment>();
            attachmentByParentIds.Add(parentId, attachmentList);
        }
        attachmentList.Add(attachment);
    }
}

private void AddHeaderAttachment(AAttachment attachment) 
{
    AddHeaderAttachment(x => x.AAttachmentByParentIds, attachment);
}

private void AddHeaderAttachment(BAttachment attachment) 
{
    AddHeaderAttachment(x => x.BAttachmentByParentIds, attachment);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) :

```
private void AddAttachable<T>(....) where T:Attachable
```

the full code looking something like this:

```
private void AddAttachable<T>(T attachment, Func<MyCollection, Dictionary<string,T>> getFunc) 
     where T:Attachable  
{
string parentId = attachment.ParentId;
if (this.collectionByIds.TryGetValue(attachment.Id, out MyCollection collection)) {
    // func is used here
    if (!getFunc(collection).TryGetValue(parentId, out List<T> attachmentList)) {
        attachmentList = new List<T>();
        // and here, can be moved to variable
        getFunc(collection).Add(parentId, attachmentList);
    }
    attachmentList.Add(attachment);
}
}
```

and usage

```
BAttachment bAttach = ...
AddAttachment(bAttach, col => col.BAttachmentByParentIds )
```

Comment: I'm rather new at C# and have little experience with generics in any language.  I would very much like to use generics, but would need more details how they might be applied to create a complete working solution.  Also, you still reference the concrete `BAttachmentByParentIds` in the above code.

Comment: @BrianKessler a little bit more cleaned up)

Comment: This looks very promising!  I'll try this.  Thanks!.  :-)

Comment: (Nit, but it's probably also worth caching the value returned from `getFunc`)

Comment: @canton7, Sounds like a good idea, but how would I add the caching?  I get the general idea, but wouldn't the extra step to check if it has been cached cost more in performance than just getting it again since it is passed by reference?  Or am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: I just mean `var attachmentByParentIds = getFunc(collection)` below the `// func is used here` line, and then use `attachmentByParentIds` in the two places where `getFunc(collection)` is currently used

Comment: @BrianKessler by caching, i assume, he means moving two calls `getFunc(collection)` to one separate variable (like stated in the second comment in my code)

Comment: @canton7, Guru Stron, I see!  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can only choose one correct answer.. Everyone has been very helpful, but ultimately, I like @GuruStron's answer best.